# bundler install RAILS_ENV=test installs all gems again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, bundler

I was trying to install just my test gems and suddenly bundler tried to install ALL gems again. Why is this so? shouldn't it be looking at the same gemset as my dev?

```
bundle install RAILS_ENV=test
Fetching git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
remote: Counting objects: 3652, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1337/1337), done.
remote: Total 3652 (delta 2389), reused 3331 (delta 2193)
Receiving objects: 100% (3652/3652), 574.45 KiB | 15 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2389/2389), done.
Fetching git://github.com/stalcottsmith/rails3_acts_as_paranoid.git
remote: Counting objects: 250, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (202/202), done.
remote: Total 250 (delta 131), reused 93 (delta 44)
Receiving objects: 100% (250/250), 45.66 KiB | 30 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (131/131), done.
Fetching git://github.com/stalcottsmith/watir.git
remote: Counting objects: 15547, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5377/5377), done.
remote: Total 15547 (delta 10218), reused 14217 (delta 9908)
Receiving objects: 100% (15547/15547), 8.64 MiB | 18 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10218/10218), done.
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index for http://gemcutter.org/
Installing rake (0.8.7) 
Installing abstract (1.0.0) 
Installing activesupport (3.0.3) 
Installing builder (2.1.2) 
Installing i18n (0.5.0) 
Installing activemodel (3.0.3) 
Installing erubis (2.6.6) 
Installing rack (1.2.1) 
Installing rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Installing rack-test (0.5.7) 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Installing actionpack (3.0.3) 
Installing mime-types (1.16) 
Installing polyglot (0.3.1) 
Installing treetop (1.4.9) 
Installing mail (2.2.14) 
Installing actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Installing arel (2.0.7) 
Installing activerecord (3.0.3) 
Installing activeresource (3.0.3) 
Installing acts_as_versioned (0.6.0) 
Installing andand (1.3.1) 
Installing annotate (2.4.0) 
Installing hoe (2.8.0) 
Installing ar_fixtures (0.0.4) 
Installing archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2) 
Using authlogic (2.1.3) from git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git (at rails3) 
Using bundler (1.0.7) 
Installing celerity (0.8.7) 
Installing culerity (0.2.14) 
Installing nokogiri (1.4.4) with native extensions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TROLOLOL!

apparently `bundler install <something>` will install all your gems in that folder. I just found out when I saw an uncommitted folder named "RAILS_ENV=test/" when I did git status.

As an added note, it "remembers" the old path so any subsequent bundle installs created that RAILS_ENV=test/ folder again. To reset it, use:

```
bundler install --system
```

Comment: ROFL I did that too, just now, not paying attention.  I remember reading about this "feature" when bundler first came out, now I fell for it.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is

```
bundle install --system
```

Tested on Bundler version 1.0.10

Comment: actually wanted to install the test environment gems